# How may I restrict my API to only be accessed by the Frontend only

Tags: reactjs, rest, next.js, game-development

I'm building a game, and someone has exploited the API

How may I choose a list of "allowed domains" that can fetch through my API? My previous API was used by someone to increase their in-game money.

Comment: Set specific url to your backend CORS

Comment: Can all users access your API or only logged in users? Is [authenticated routes](https://cheatcode.co/tutorials/how-to-handle-authenticated-routes-with-next-js) an option for your usecase? You can also try [checking the referer](https://vinayak-nandi.medium.com/nextjs-how-to-get-document-referer-requesting-path-c51a4584b3d4)

Comment: @kiranvj, I'm currently using NextAuth for authentication, I've tried making it an authenticated route but failed.

Answer (score 0):

The comment and answer referring to the usage of `CORS` aren't solving the problem of someone exploiting your API. Everyone can write a program to simply set the `Origin` header themselves.
Increase your security by securing the API with any sort of credentials, e.g. api tokens. And then build your logic in a way that it isn't possible to perform those tampering actions.

Validate on server-side that the request is valid (why would anyone be able to simply increase the money by hitting an endpoint, they should do e.g. a quest and your server validates that it was successfully done and rewards the money).

Comment: The current system to "give money" is by selling items, so whenever someone sells an item, the api is called via "PUT" which sets the new money in the database using prisma.

Comment: @FSCYT Then you need an inventory check. I'm pretty sure you have some sort of database which says which amount of which itemID a specific userID has right? So if someone sells more than he has, you deny it (and log it to ban them if needed)

Answer (score -1):

Learn about CORS Policy and implement it on your API Backend. Most probably, if you are using any of the popular frameworks to build your backend, you will already have this setting. You may just need to enable it and add your frontend IP/URL to it.

Comment: Any idea about NextJS using NextAuth?

Comment: No. I am Python Developer so I know that a CORS setting do exists in Django backend. I don't know about Next JS.